# Magento 2 - When to use the parameter `@_prefix: 1` when calling mixin .lib-css()?

Tags: magento2, less, ui

I wonder when I need to use the parameter `@_prefix: 1` with `.lib-css()`

I always use it with the css [transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) property

```
.lib-css(transform, scale(0.65), @_prefix: 1);
```

so that it generates this code:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
```

How can I easily figure out if I should use `@_prefix: 1`?

I think I only use it for new special properties but not for default ones like "padding".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some websites which can help to figure it out.

http://shouldiprefix.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to checking https://autoprefixer.github.io/ as it can vary depending on how far back you want to support.